# Does Blue light filters in smartphones really work?

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles, melatonin, effectiveness

Since this is more of a health related question, asking this here is preferable than other sites. 
So, does such apps really do not disturb the production of melatonin?

**Does Blue light filters in smartphones really work? Are they really that effective?**

Comment: I've wondered the same thing myself! Thanks for asking!!

Comment: https://justgetflux.com/ related.